# Find index in bitmask

Tags: sql, sqlite, binary

Halo Binary experts out there,

I have a bitmask representing **ON** options of a room, say `11001 (Opt #1, 4, 5)`
Another user tries to search with his own bitmask (say `111000 (Opt #4, 5, 6)`
Doing a `(Room | Search) != 0` means it compares the mask and see if there's a same switch **ON** (In this case #4)
The thing is, switch **#4** is the 2nd 'active' switch of the Room, and the 1st for the 'Search'.
I need the user to also find that **#4** is the 2nd switch of the Room.

User have the separate bitmask to check against.
Both Room and User can only have 3 switch on

My approach can know which is the last(biggest) index, using UserMask2 for example(3rd option):

```
if(RoomMask | UserMask2 != 0) A = (RoomMask - UserMask2 = 11001 - 10000 = 01001).
```

`if (A < RoomMask)` *UserMask2 is the 3rd switch because minus-ing by UserMask2 makes it lower than UserMask2*

This only finds if a certain UserMask is indeed on the RoomMask' biggest bit.

But I'm not sure how to continue.

This is used for Matchmaking search using Photon, which uses **SQL** and I probably have to manage to do this with a single WHERE query(not sure if it can store variables.)

https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/lobby-and-matchmaking/matchmaking-and-lobby#sql_lobby_type

I hope I'm clear enough
Cheers!

Comment: Please provide the expected output

Comment: So when User checks RoomMask with his individual SearchMask:
FindBitIndex(RoomMask, SearchMask1) = 11001, 1000 = 2
FindBitIndex(RoomMask, SearchMask2) = 11001, 10000 = 3
FindBitIndex(RoomMask, SearchMask1) = 11001, 100000 = invalid (because RoomMask does not contain 100000)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear and hence I'm not 100% that this answer is what you are looking for. Still, here you have.

You can search for contents of columns using the `like` key, where you have two wildcards:

- `%` means **anything**,
- `_` means **any character**.

Now, suppose that you want to find a match for switches 1, 4 and 7 in a map of, say, 10 possible switches (being 1 the leftmost in this example), you could use the clause:

```
WHERE Bitmap like '1__1__1___`
```

of course, this is just an example and you would need to adapt it to your specific context.